# How to do a scatter plot with factor class on Xlim?

Tags: r, class, scatter-plot, jitter

When I try to do a scatter plot with jitter, i found it require the `Xlim` to be numeric

```
plot(jitter(d$'WHO region'), d$Numeric)
> Error in jitter(d$"WHO region") : 'x' must be numeric
```

so when I try to change the column to numeric, the output on scatter with jitter became unreadable

```
as.numeric(as.character(d$'WHO region'))
```

[image]

Please be aware that the WHO region column is Factor as i found character class does not work with scatter plot.

Below is the code i used to input the data

```
d <- read_csv("WHOSIS_000008.csv", col_types = cols(`WHO region` = col_factor(levels = c("Africa","Americas", "Eastern Mediterranean","Europe", "South-East Asia", "Western Pacific"))))
```

The result I am supposed to get.

[image]

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` i.e. `dput(head(d, 40))`

Comment: it said too long to post here so i did this, 
> dput(head(d$`WHO region`, 10))
structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Africa", 
"Americas", "Eastern Mediterranean", "Europe", "South-East Asia", 
"Western Pacific"), class = "factor")

Comment: Do you need `plot(dvec, jitter(as.numeric(dvec)), col = "blue")` where `dvec <- $"WHO region"`

Comment: it also generates something similar to what i got, the data from column WHO.region will be convert to 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: The code `plot(dvec, jitter(as.numeric(dvec)), col = "blue")` gives x axis the factor values and. not the storage integer values.  the `jitter` function requires a numeric input i.e. you can check the documentation `?jitter`

Answer (score 1):

Using the `iris` data set and `stripchart` this is pretty close:

```
data(iris)
stripchart(Sepal.Length~Species, iris, method="jitter", vertical=TRUE, pch=16, col="blue")
mns <- with(iris, tapply(Sepal.Length, Species, mean))
segments((1:3)-.1, mns, (1:3)+.1, mns, lwd=3, col="red")
```

[image: Strip Plot]

Comment: BIG THANKS to you for this solution! after @akrun said about numeric ONLY works with numbers i started thinking about the possibility of using other methods as well. too bad i cant upvote your comment. indeed a great and clean solution!